# WebDav: How to set Exchange 2003 appointment category?

Tags: c#, outlook, exchange-server, webdav, independentsoft

I am using [Independentsoft's WebDav API](http://www.independentsoft.de/webdavex/index.html) to create a calendar appointment. I would like to set the category of the appointment.

In Outlook, I would set the category as indicated here: 
[Outlook image http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/b51648a90c.gif](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/b51648a90c.gif)

How would I assign the category using the WebDav API?

Most other fields are simply properties of the appointment object:

```
Appointment appt = new Appointment();
appt.Body = "body";
appt.MeetingStatus = MeetingStatus.Tentative;
```

And so on. I have not been able to find a property that corresponds to category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have discovered the answer to this.

The property is Keywords. It's a string array.

So, to set a category, you would do this:

```
appt.Keywords = new string[] { "CategoryName" };
```

I assume you can add multiple categories in the same way:

```
appt.Keywords = new string[] { "CategoryName1", "CategoryName2" };
```

Comment: Bless your heart for finding this :).